# Can I use PsExec or similar tool to determine if a remote PC is already logged in?

Tags: psexec, sysinternals

I'm writing a utility which lets you remotely run a test application on network PCs. I plan to use PsExec to remotely launch the application on each PC but I need to check

- The PC is reachable
- The PC is logged in to Windows

Now I assume PsExec will simply fail if either of these isn't the case but is that the best option or is there a nice way to explicitly check?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with other SysInternals tools, I think:

1. **PSLoggedOn** to see names of users logged on (can be used for a remote computer)
2. **PsList** to see a list of processes running remotely, can also be useful.